# Android MediaPlayer buffered data reset after seekTo is called

Tags: android, media-player, buffering, seek

Everytime I call seekTo() when streaming a file on my mediaPlayer, the already buffered percentage is reseted.
Is there a way not to restart buffering some part of my file that has already been buffered when using seekto ?

Answer (score 1):

No, AFAIK you don't have any control over buffering. You can't even tell it how much you want to buffer.

Comment: Ok but it seems weird that you can't 'seekTo' a position already buffered without starting re-buffering information you already had.
Maybe it's a bug in 2.2. I'll try it on ICS tomorrow.